# PT1H37M21S language format

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert the following forward into a time object?

```
PT1H37M21S
```

Or is it required that a do `splits` and `strips`, etc. in order to extract the time object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format strings to parse date/times. You can either use Python's datetime [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) directly or more human-friend Arrow library [arrow.get()](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/#creation) (see parse string).

The format does not look like any common datetime format so you need to write your own parser formatter.

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are often better than splits and strips.

```
from datetime import time
import re

m = re.match(r'^PT([0-9]+)H([0-9]+)M([0-9]+)S$', 'PT1H37M21S')
t = time(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2)), int(m.group(3)))
# t is now datetime.time(1, 37, 21)
```

(I don't know what `PT` means so I hope it's just a prefix.)